# Automata edge arrows that go straight to the left do not appear properly

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, automata

Simply put, If I make an automata with the following code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture} [node distance = 2cm, on grid]
 
\node (q0) [state,
    initial,
    initial left,
    initial distance=1.5cm,
    initial text=Start here
] {$q_0$};
 
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I get the correct expected output:
[image]

but if I instead have the arrow coming in from the right:

```
\begin{tikzpicture} [node distance = 2cm, on grid]
 
\node (q0) [state,
    initial,
    initial right,
    initial distance=1.5cm,
    initial text=Start here
] {$q_0$};
 
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I get this:
[image]

In fact, any arrow that is straight and points to the left displays incorrectly like this. Any advice for fixing this?

Comment: As you can read in the answer below, it's very important to insert a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) within your question to help us understand where your issue comes from. Short code snippets like those you provided remain unclear.

Answer (score 2):

The unfortunate output you obtain is due to some ingredient that you do not disclose, possibly some `\tikzset` command that should not be there. This code illustrates that the problem does not exist a priori but can result from some inappropriate global setting.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2cm, on grid]
 
\node (q0) [state,
    initial,
    initial left,
    initial distance=1.5cm,
    initial text=Start here
] {$q_0$};
 
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2cm, on grid]
 
\node (q0) [state,
    initial,
    initial right,
    initial distance=1.5cm,
    initial text=Start here
] {$q_0$};
 
\end{tikzpicture}

\tikzset{every picture/.append style={xscale=-1}}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2cm, on grid]
 
\node (q0) [state,
    initial,
    initial right,
    initial distance=1.5cm,
    initial text=Start here
] {$q_0$};
 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, the last picture is messed up, but only after some global `\tikzset` was invoked.